# Разделение переменной

Tags: php

У меня есть переменная

```
$test = rand(100,  9999) . '-' . $id;
```

Эта переменная передается в другой файл. Как сделать так, чтобы в другом файле `$test` разбивалась на три части и только `$id` выводило?

Comment: А массив чем не угодил?

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = "ЭТО_АЙДИ_БЕЙБИ";
$test = rand(100, 9999) . ' - ' . $id;
$var = explode(' ', $test);
echo $var[2];
echo "<br>";
print_r($var);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: $var[2] уже полноценная переменная? Ее можно применять?

Comment: @TheAs110z, а что вы имеете ввиду под "полноценной переменной"?)

Comment: ее можно применять к операторам?

Comment: Проверьте еще правильность формирования переменной тест. Я хочу чтобы  test был примерное такой. 123213(рандом) - 111. А в другом файле выводило только 111.

Comment: @TheAs110z добавил результат выполнения куска кода и более наглядный пример, посмотрите, может отпадут вопросы ;)

Answer (score 1):

Вы написали что хотите что переменная $test развивалась на три части.
Какие? Пример если можно.
Ее можно разбить на две части

```
$id = 123456
$test = "866433-".$id;
$onlyid = explode("-", $test)[1]; //$onlyid = 123456;
```